# ES6 class with private/protected properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have a ES6 class as below

```
class CoffeeMachine {
  constructor(power) {
    this._power = power;
  }
  get power() {
    return this._power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine 
let coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(100);

console.log(coffeeMachine);
```

I have 2 questions;

1. For the console.log(coffeeMachine), I get below;

> ```
> CoffeeMachine {
> _power: 100,
> __proto__:
> power: 100
> }
> ```

I can see that "power" is on the **proto** of CoffeeMachine and also has the same value i.e. 100
How does that happen considering I am not setting "power" explicitly anywhere ?

2. Is it really possible to implement a private/protected in this example ? I know there is #privateVar in the latest ES, but wanted to know if it can be emulated in this code ?

Comment: I mean the concept of public, private, protected just exists for the programmer and the compiler which then complains... The computer doesn't care. If you tell him to access a certain memory offset of a class it does it... So as long as you treat it as `private`, just without the error, it should be no issue ^^. But maybe try typescript? :)

Comment: @elias given that typescript in the end gets compiled to js ...

Comment: @JonasWilms I... don't get your point... like I just described. Access modifiers are only there to provide orientation for the programmer. The computer itself doesn't actually care. And you should definitely not base your security model or something similar on access modifiers.

Comment: So coming back to the original question, is there no way of emulating "private" properties...I was referring to this page for reference https://javascript.info/private-protected-properties-methods

Comment: "*How does that happen?*" - depends on the implementation of `console.log`. What environment did you run this code in?

Answer (score 2):

getters and setters are [*transparent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_(human%E2%80%93computer_interaction)), meaning that an observer (the console) cannot distinguish between a regular property and a getter / setter.

> How does that happen considering I am not setting "power" explicitly anywhere ?

I guess that's the console evaluates all values of the object once, then it associates those values to the respective object owning those properties. Otherwise it would have to evaluate the getter twice (once for the object and once for the prototype) and that behaviour is probably unwanted.

You can manually evaluate the getter on the prototype though:

```js
class See { get me() { return "now"; } }

console.log(See.prototype.me);
```

> Is it really possible to implement a private/protected in this example ?

Yes, using an IIFE around a Map that is certainly possible in ES6:

```
 const Private = (() => {
    const priv = new WeakMap();

    return class {
      get priv() { return priv.get(this); }
      set priv(v) { priv.set(this, v); }
    };
 })();
```

But, as pointed out in the comments already, you probably don't need that. And for ES2020 there are private properties just as you said.

Comment: I was about to say... What exactly do you mean by `transparent` `rgba(0,0,0,0)`? :D Maybe provide a MDN refference? ^^

Comment: @elias added a reference

Comment: @JonasWilms That map thingy is interesting! But I guess it kinda ruins the purpose of classes, doesn't it?.. I sure love-hate javascript :D

Comment: never used it. Also never needed private properties. I'm fine without them

Comment: I think they are handy to provide guidance for the programmer. That's why I use typescript all the time.

Comment: The `Map` example will cause memory leaks as each object created will never be garbage collected.  I think this is where a `WeakMap` is supposed to be used.

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the private variable with a `#` prefix. Example:

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  #_power;
  constructor(power) {
    this.#_power = power;
  }
  get power() {
    return this.#_power;
  }
}

// create the coffee machine 
let coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(100);

console.log(coffeeMachine);
console.log(coffeeMachine._power);
console.log(coffeeMachine.power);
```

Comment: Thanks....While I am aware of that syntax, is it possible to emulate in my code without #

Comment: Not if you want them to be hidden in your object. I believe you have to use `#` for that.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_fields

Comment: It's kind of interesting that TypeScript doesn't transpile private fields to this syntax: https://stackblitz.com/edit/uyg7rm?file=index.ts

Comment: Probably because only chromium seems to support it

Comment: It'll gain traction at some point. But, yes, the reason why it's probably not implemented in typescript is because the support isn't there.

Comment: I just don't get why they used #... why not... Idk... `private`? I mean `static` isn't already a keyword... oh wait..

Comment: @mwilson Typescript `private` properties are still normal properties, they just throw compile errors when you access them.